# Inconsistent float operation results between clang and gcc

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, clang

Compiled and run separately on OSX 10.10 and ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include<float.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void testAtan() {
  float temp1 = 62981764.0000000000000000f;
  float temp2 = (2.14859168E8f  *  atanf(temp1));
  printf("temp2: %.16f\n", temp2);
}

int main() {
  printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD=%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
  testAtan();
  return 0;
}
```

On OS X, it prints

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0
temp2: 337499968.0000000000000000
```

while on ubuntu, it prints

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0
temp2: 337500000.0000000000000000
```

Any ideas to justify this and ways to make the results consistent?

Comment: A 32-bit IEEE754 float only has about 7 decimal digits worth of precision, so the two results *are* consistent. That's what "precision" means.

Comment: A hint to the reason can be found in the comments for Apple's `atanf` implementation: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/atanf.s  Someone else should be able to take it from there.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If that's what "precision" means, then that's not what "32-bit IEEE754 float" means.  The two results he's showing differ by an ulp.

Comment: @KerrekSB This comment reflects a confusion between the *precision* of a format and the *accuracy* of an operation. The binary32 IEEE 754 format has (the equivalent of) 7 decimal digits of precision, but the results of two basic operations applied to the same arguments on two different IEEE 754-compilant platforms can be expected to be equal to 2^-1000000000000, because they can be expected to be the same. Just because the precision is about 7 decimal digits does not mean that two computations should differ by that. They can differ by more, or they can differ by less (by being identical).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yes, good point, the ambiguity comes indeed from the lack of accuracy constraints on the library functions (and even on basic operations sometimes; C does not mandate IEEE754 operational semantics even if it uses the standard data type representation).

Answer (score 8):

You are calling a library function, `atanf`, that is not required by the IEEE 754 standard to be implemented so accurately that it would produce the same results for all implementations.

Most implementations have an accuracy of a fraction above 0.5 ULP, but that is still enough for difficult-to-round results (results for which the real result is close to the midpoint between two floats) to differ. For instance, if the real result is 0.4 ULP from the float f1 in the direction of f2, an implementation can return f1 and another return f2 and they would still both be accurate to 0.6 ULP (which is very good but not unusual).

If you wish to obtain the same results everywhere, you should incorporate your own implementation of `atanf`, made of only basic IEEE 754 operations. Then it will produce the same results on all compilation platforms that offer IEEE 754 semantics for the basic operations (that is, most compilation platforms). This is what Java did to make floating-point elementary functions results reproducible: it standardized on [the “netlib” implementation](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/). If you manage to compile it on the other platforms that you wish to target, you could use the [Apple implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/atanf.s) pointed out by Stephen Canon: like many other functions in OS X's math library, it provides excellent standards compliance, and a very good trade-off between accuracy and speed.

You also have to possibility to use any “correctly rounded” math library, and then the results will be the same as for any other correctly rounded math library, because there is only one correctly rounded result for any application of an elementary function to any argument. One correctly rounded library is [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/), but the point is that you could use any other one and obtain the same results as CRlibm. CRlibm only offers functions for double-precision, but I would be very surprised if any argument of any single-precision standard function produced a different result when correctly rounded directly to single-precision as opposed to correctly rounded to double-precision then rounded to single-precision.

**EDIT:**

In the particular case of large arguments passed to a single-precision arctangent function, there is one more reason why an implementation may voluntarily choose a result other than the most precise result it computed: an implementation may consider it desirable to have the function always return a result between -π/2 and π/2. For very large arguments, the real result is nearly π/2, and the closest single-precision floating-point approximation to π/2 happens to be above π/2. Some implementations of `atanf` choose to return the float immediately below π/2 in these cases, while other implementations can choose to return the float immediately above (and nearest to) π/2. I discussed this in a [blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/03/correct-rounding-or-mathematically-correct-rounding) (but take my opinion with a grain of salt: I do not use floating-point much, so my opinion shouldn't matter). The blog post is framed in the context of double-precision, but actually, in double-precision, we are lucky (for the particular case of function `atan`): the nearest `double` approximation to π/2 happens to be below it, so that no choice is actually necessary.

Comment: I think [libmpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/) is one of the standard C libraries for correct rounding. I think that's what GCC uses (since 4.6) to implement constant expression evaluation.

Comment: @PascalCuoq float(double(exact)) may cause double rounding. Yes it should be rare, but it's exactly the difference between well rounded (near 0.5 ulp) and correctly rounded.

Comment: @aka.nice It is possible to find instances of double rounding for arbitrary functions or choices of precisions. I was only making my dubious claim in the particular case of a usual elementary function rounded from double to single, and I was using the hand-wavy statistical argument at slide 49 in http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/documents/cern.pdf to do so (exact midpoint results are exact in `double`. Non-exact midpoints should be wrong by at least half a `double` ULP, which sounds plausible enough).

Comment: @aka.nice Of course, this is single-precision and it would be easy enough to check this with exhaustive testing, but I am not curious enough.

Comment: This is generally an excellent answer, but what's going on for `atanf(huge)` is a fascinating special case that merits some added detail.  The mathematically exact result is (pi/2 - tiny), which is bracketed by two single precision values, L < atan(huge) < U.  U (the result produced by glibc) is slightly closer to the mathematically exact result, so it seems at first to be the more correct of the two.  However, U > pi/2, so returning U does not satisfy the constraint that the result be in the interval [-pi/2, pi/2].  This is why we chose to return L in the OS X math library.

Comment: @StephenCanon Ah yes, I didn't notice the question was about this. I wrote this a long time ago, which has the advantage of pointing to additional snippets of documentation: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/03/correct-rounding-or-mathematically-correct-rounding

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Having an arctangent function return a value for which cos(x) is negative seems wrong.  I wish IEEE had designed their trig functions to use units of 2pi or pi/2 radians; in that case, the limit of atan(x) would be a precise representable number whose cosine would be positive zero.  I would think computing trig functions with such angles would be both easier in hardware and more generally useful; there are lots of cases where using radians causes trouble, and I'm hard-pressed to think of non-contrived cases where it's actually helpful.

Comment: @supercat There are so many `cospi`, … implementations that I didn't think that it wasn't part of IEEE 754. They are functions that compute f(πx) for f in sin, cos, tan. CRlibm has a set of `…pi` trigonometric functions. On the other hand, I don't remember seeing any `overpiarctan` implementation anywhere.

Comment: @PascalCuoq let's use naively false stats: the first 24 bits are 1.xx...x0| the next 31 must not be |100...0|1 otherwise we'll round twice down instead of once up we have a bit less than 2^32 finite float on input, if we assume a uniform distribution of the int formed by next 31 bits, it's not completely unlucky. OK if function f is (anti)symmetric f(-u)=+/-f(u), there's less than 2^31 finite inputs, but we have another annoying bit pattern 1.xxx...1|0111....1|1. Well this is very approximative, but maybe it's worth scanning all the floats, we have several functions in the libm...

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Many implementations have sin2pi(x) etc. functions, though they differ in accuracy; making a good function is easy on machines with working 80-bit math, but much harder on machines without. BTW, am I the only person who would rather see a well-supported floating-point data type which behaves like an 80-bit float plus 48 bits of padding, than a 128-bit floating-point type?  The marginal benefit gained from a well-supported type that had an extra 16 bits over a `double` would be much greater than one with another 48 bits beyond that.

Comment: @PascalCuoq For the fun, the probability of seeing a specific face when rolling a fair N-faces dice N times is=1-((N-1)/N)^N; when N is big enough that is approx. 1-e^-1 or 63%... Not sure how fair are the next 30 bits though. All this is a bit like the shadoks constructing and launching 1 million rockets because there is 1 out of a million chance of success each - http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Shadoks.